# How to use Android DownloadManager ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE?

Tags: android

I am using Android Download Manager class to download file from web. The Download Manager doesn't display error by default when there is not insufficient storage. I know how to check for current storage available and compare it with current file size before downloading it with following code:

```
public boolean isSpaceAvailable(long bytes) {
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
    long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getBlockCount();

    return true;
}
```

But I would like to use **ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE** instead. How can I use this?

[Android DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I have `Cursor` to check if it moves to first and then check for `COLUMN_STATUS':

```
private void checkStatus(Cursor cursor){
    //column for status
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
    int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
    //column for reason code if the download failed or paused
    int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
    int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);
    //get the download filename
    int filenameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
    String filename = cursor.getString(filenameIndex);

    String statusText = "";
    String reasonText = "";

    switch(status){
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
            statusText = "STATUS_FAILED";
            switch(reason){
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ERROR";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                    reasonText = "ERROR_UNKNOWN";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
            statusText = "STATUS_PAUSED";
            switch(reason){
                case DownloadManager.PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI:
                    reasonText = "PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN:
                    reasonText = "PAUSED_UNKNOWN";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK:
                    reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK";
                    break;
                case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY:
                    reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
            statusText = "STATUS_PENDING";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
            statusText = "STATUS_RUNNING";
            break;
        case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
            statusText = "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL";
            reasonText = "Filename:\n" + filename;
            break;
    }
    Log.d("Error", statusText + " " + reasonText);
}
```

And then calling the method:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) checkStatus(cursor);
```

Cite: [Android Download Manager Example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-downloadmanager-example.html)